# Temporizadores y botones con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un temporizador con JavaScript, y cabe aclarar, que no se NADA de JavaScript, solo muy básico. El tema es que ahora lo que quiero hacer (que no esta en el codigo) es que cuando el temporizador llega a cero, debe de activarse un botón, si el tiempo todavia no se cumplió, esta desactivado. Si alguno tiene alguna idea, seria de gran ayuda.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en"> 
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Temporizador</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="bloque">
     <p>Dias</p>
    <div class="dias" id="dias">00</div>
    </div>
   <div class="bloque">
     <p>Horas</p>
   <div class="horas" id="horas">--</div>
   </div>
   <p>Minutos</p>
   <div class="minutos" id="minutos">--</div>  
   </div>
   <p>Segundos</p>
   <div class="segundos" id="segundos">--</div>
   </div>
   <script src="let horas = 7;.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Ahora, JavaScript:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Perdon que todavia no puse el codigo de javascript, se me complica y estoy aprendiendo a poner el codigo en las notas, pero es mas que nada para alguna idea.
Se que con boostrap esta la opcion  `disabled` que desabilita botones, pero no se como conectarla al temporizador.

Muchas gracias por la atencion

Comment: Agrega el código de JS como texto, no como imagen, así como hiciste con el HTML.

Answer (score 0):

yo nose mucho de bootstrap pero se que las cosas en bootstrap se manejan por clases, imagino que "disabled" es una clase del framework, entonces lo que podes hacer es que cuando el temporizador termine, le borras una clase al boton dinamicamente podes hacerlo con **boton.classList.remove("disabled")**. **boton** es la variable con la que obtenes el elemento, en vez de poner document.getElementById cada vez que quieras obtener un elemento, lo haces una vez y el valor lo guardas en una variable

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).